# How to deploy Django app VPS using Apache2?

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, django-deployment

I'v followed this tutorial which is recommended by various tutorial to deploy Django.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

This is the content of my 000-default.conf file ..

UPDATED ".conf" file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

 Alias /static /home/myproject/static
<Directory /home/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/myproject/myprojectenv python-path=/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This is my first experience to deploy  Django web-app on  VPS which is equipped with "ubuntu-16.04-64bit".

I am able to fetch "myproject" Django app while  virtualenv is activated and with Django default server like this:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and able to successfully open myproject app with my_ip,  which is represented by "xx.xxx.xxx.xx" and port 8000.

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8000
```

While, after deactivating the virtualenv and configuring  the apache2 server as described by given tutorial its not working.

As tutorial says, after successful installation  and configuring your Django app on server it  should work only with your IP like this:

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

Which is not working in my case rather its showing "Waiting for xx.xxx.xxx.xx...." for infinity on browser..  and page shows error like this..

```
This site can’t be reached

xx.xxx.xxx.63 refused to connect.
Search Google for 188 167 8000
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And also its not producing any log for apache2

```
ErrorLog /home/error.log
CustomLog /home/access.log combined
```

I am struggling since morning but not succeeded please help...

**UPDATE**

**Apache2 error log:**

```
   [Thu Nov 09 03:38:23.800566 2017] [core:warn] [pid 8823:tid 140238720010112] AH00045: child process 8827 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Thu Nov 09 03:38:25.802552 2017] [core:warn] [pid 8823:tid 140238720010112] AH00045: child process 8827 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Thu Nov 09 03:38:27.804431 2017] [core:warn] [pid 8823:tid 140238720010112] AH00045: child process 8827 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Thu Nov 09 03:38:29.805890 2017] [core:error] [pid 8823:tid 140238720010112] AH00046: child process 8827 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Thu Nov 09 03:38:30.806571 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8823:tid 140238720010112] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Nov 09 03:38:31.551724 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8960:tid 140082895366016] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 09 03:38:31.551837 2017] [core:notice] [pid 8960:tid 140082895366016] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site


ImportError: No module named site
```

this is my "wsgi.py" content

```
"""
WSGI config for myproject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: DocumentRoot should be /home/myproject/myproject/. There are also couple of other things to edit but firstly try it.

Comment: not working.. same behavior :(:( :(

Comment: another thing is that you have to use python-home instead of python-path in which you have to specify the path to virtual environment python-home=/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv

Comment: yeh apache2 giving similar  error in error  log,  I have updated in Question

Comment: did this error appear after you switched to python-home?

Comment: no it was appearing before also. Though, I have changed the python-home but same error coming again n again ..no change :(

Comment: can you post your wsgi.py?

Comment: "wsgi.py" Updated in man body

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov ``DocumentRoot`` should not be set to where the project code is. That is a very bad practice as it is one step towards making it so that people can download your application code. So avoid doing that and best not to recommend to others that they do it. There is no need to.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thanks, I will try it on my server now.

Comment: @jax don't use my first hint and remove it from config. It is not required.

Answer (score 0):

For how to setup mod_wsgi with a virtual environment correctly, see:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Your problem with `ImportError: No module named site` looks like you mod_wsgi may not be compiled for the same Python version you want to use. See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#multiple-python-versions

as it is a variation on that problem.

Go through all the installation checks in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html

Comment: thanks there is one problem that I have found with this documents is that "sys.prefix" says install python path is '/usr' instead of '/usr/local'

Comment: The value of ``sys.prefix`` will be different depending on whether you are using system Python, Python you installed yourself, or want to link it to a virtual environment. Set ``WSGIPythonHome`` or ``python-home`` based on ``sys.prefix`` as your Python shows, not what the docs give as an example.

Comment: I really don't get it what you want to say.. You mn to say I have to set  python-home as python-home=/usr, because this is what sys.prefix command tell me about the system python installation path

Comment: Your comment wasn't clear to begin with so didn't know what you are asking or trying to point out. I could only restate what the documentation effectively says. The case of ``sys.prefix`` being ``/usr`` is a special case as it indicates it is the system Python version. In that case, you can usually skip setting it because the Python interpreter initialisation will find the system Python first usually, but it is still recommended if you have multiple Python installations of the same version installed in different locations.

Comment: Can you explain better what you were saying is a problem. Are you saying you think the documentation is wrong?

Comment: Hahahahaha  @Graham, l I am not saying that document is incorrect. I don't have this much knowledge to declare these documents wrong.   I just said I'din't get your point in earlier comment so just trying to clarify.